# Convertir key a base64 sin necesidad de POSTMAN?

Tags: javascript, api, postman

Una pregunta tengo una llave secreta provista por una api que sirve como auth basic, lo testee con postman y lo que aprecio es que convierte esa cadena a base64

Intente convertir esa cadena con paginas online y con un btoa(sk_text); ya en mi desarrollo, pero lo que aprecio es que no me da el mismo resultado de la conversión que postman.

Alguien me podría decir su POSTMAN lo codifica en otro modo o usa otro modelo

Comment: base64 no es una encripcion.. es una codificacion para pasar cualquier cosa a una cadena de texto... la mayoria de los lenguajes de programacion tienen una funcion para transformar a base 64...

Comment: Gracias hice la corrección en la pregunta, en efecto lo estoy tratando de hacer con typescript con la función btoa() pero no da el mismo resultado que POSTMAN

Comment: podrias mostrar como lo haces, un ejemplo de cadena y como termina transformada en los dos lados?

Comment: tienes un solo token? porque en basic auth se usa usuario y contraseña y se la codifica en base64 separada por dos puntos "usuario:contraseña"

Comment: lo adjunte abajo la api solo proporciona la sk que es la que se manda en user no hace uso de password

Comment: @GustavoLopezCallejas en ese caso a lo que le tienes que aplicar base64 es a "estoeslacadenaaconvertir:" (con dos puntos al final)

Answer (score 0):

Adjunto imagen de la llave que se debe convertir y como lo hace POSTMAN en sus snippets que genera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si el header es

```
  Authorization: Basic ZXN0b2VzbGFjYWRlbmFhY29udmVydGlyOg==
```

Ahí dice:

- el nombre del header es `Authorization`
- el tipo de autorización es `AUTH_BASIC`
- el contenido del `AUTH_BASIC` es `ZXN0b2VzbGFjYWRlbmFhY29udmVydGlyOg==`

Si decodificas base64 de `ZXN0b2VzbGFjYWRlbmFhY29udmVydGlyOg==` obtienes `estoeslacadenaaconvertir:`

```js
console.log(atob('ZXN0b2VzbGFjYWRlbmFhY29udmVydGlyOg=='))
```

Y a la inversa, la UI de postman, cuando le dices que el tipo de autenticación de AUTH_BASIC, te muestra un formulario con campos `username`  y `password`, y al enviar la petición, el programa los usará computando

```
  `Authorization: Basic ${btoa(username+':'+password)}`
```

Y eso calza:

```js
let username='estoeslacadenaaconvertir',
    password=''

console.log(`Authorization: Basic ${btoa(username+':'+password)}`)
```

Pienso que tu problema se limita a que, viendo que el password estaba vacío, simplemente te saltaste el paso se concatenar username y password, perdiendo con ello los dos puntos.